# How do I average blocks of discontinuous data using a flag?

Tags: r, average

I have a set of discontinuous data divided into blocks, which look like this:

```
X1  X2    X3
1   10.1  1
2   10.2  1
3   10.3  1
4   10.4  1
5   NA    0
6   NA    0
7   20.1  1
8   20.2  1
9   NA    0
10  NA    0
```

Basically I need to average all data with flag X3=1 in the first block (10.1,10.2,10.3,10.4), than in the second (20.1,20.2) and so on. A rolling average would not work because the blocks have slightly different sizes (in this case, the first one is 4 points, the second only 2).
I can't figure out a simple way to use the flag, without parsing the whole matrix one row at a time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, group by `rleid` of 'X3', get the `mean` of 'X2' and remove the `NA` elements in output with `na.omit`.

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(setDT(df1)[, .(MeanX2=mean(X2, na.rm=TRUE)) , .(grp= rleid(X3))])
#    grp MeanX2
#1:   1  10.25
#2:   3  20.15
```